# Prove exponential congruence with Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, chinese-remainder-theorem

How would you show that for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$

$$3^{n^4+n^2+2n+4}\equiv 21\pmod{60}.$$

As the Chinese remainder theorem is mentioned, I would start with $60=3\times4\times5$, but then how? Thank you!

Comment: You don't necessarily need to solve it, giving a good hint is good too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem tells you that $3^{n^4+n^2+2n+4}\equiv21\pmod{60}$ if and only if
$$3^{n^4+n^2+2n+4}\equiv21\pmod{q},$$
holds for all prime powers $q$ dividing $60$. You've computed $60=3\times4\times5$, so this congruence must hold for $q=3$, $q=4$ and $q=5$. Now which theorem(s) do you know that tell you when
$$a^k=1\pmod{q},$$
where $q$ is a prime (power)?

Comment: Fermat / Euler :) Thanks!